# Introducing myself on text message

Tags: greetings, email

I would like to ask which one of the following introductory is more appropriate for a formal and polite registry when I text to someone who knows me for the first time after I got her number or when I text through a different phone number than that I already have been using so in both cases there is someone knows me but cannot recognize my number unless I make  my name clear on my text.

Should I say :

> Hello, Mr./Mrs.Green. This is Jamie.

or

> Hello Mr./Mrs.Green. It is Jamie.

Comment: Either is OK if you need to be formal, but maybe you should give your full name.

Comment: I would use **This is**. You are referring to the current message, in which you are an active participant. **It is** works when we are talking about something more separate. "Who is making that announcement?" "It is Jamie."

Answer (score 4):

You should use `This is` when you are being asked to introduce yourself. for example when you join a conference call and someone asks `Who's this?` or `Who's the new caller?`

Then you should say

> Hello, Mr./Mrs.Green. This is Jamie.

But when you are introducing yourself first then you should go with following:

> Hello Mr./Mrs.Green. It is Jamie.